# Replacing Windows with Ubuntu on a Dell Laptop

Tags: drivers, dell, inspiron

I bought a Dell Inspiron 14 5000 with Windows 10 Home preinstalled on it, and would like to completely replace it with the latest version of Ubuntu. By doing this, will I have to worry about any sorts of missing drivers or anything (like the fingerprint reader) not working if I get rid of the preinstalled Windows 10 system?

If so, are there ways to remedy the situation?

Comment: Back up Windows. We often get questions on restoring Windows after totally converting as there is one application or game they must have that only runs in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should probably be fine. Fair warning though, I dual boot an XPS 15 with Win10/Ubuntu and my fingerprint reader is not supported by Ubuntu so you may want to check on that.